# SyntaxError on pageobject while accessing a select_list within fieldset

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, fieldset, page-object-gem

I'm trying to access a select_list within a fieldset though Cheezy's pageobject.

The total html is far too long to post (well over 200 lines for just the fieldset), but I can supply the lines with all of the id's and such.

fieldset:

```
<fieldset class="dartPayer-Insurance" style="width: 730px;">
```

select_list:

```
<select id="dartPayer-Payer" style="width: 235px;">
```

Line in the pageobject I am attempting to use:

```
select_list(:payer_insurance){ element(:class => "dartPayer-Insurance").select_list_element(:id => "dartPayer-PayerList") }
```

The error I am getting when I try to run my cucumber test:

```
 (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end
  {:id=>"dartPayer-Insurance"}(identifier)
                               ^ (SyntaxError)
```

This error occurs when I try to set the select_list with this line:

```
self.send(field, input)  (Where field is "payer_insurance=" and input is "UMA")
```

This line works for other pages, so I am fairly certain this is not part of the problem. I'm sure it's a simple bit of syntax in the pageobject line, but I can't find any documentation for using the pageobject quite like I'm trying to. The only reference I can find is within a previous question I asked: [Accessing a table within a table (Watir/PageObject)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116715/accessing-a-table-within-a-table-watir-pageobject)

Could anyone please tell me what I have done wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**Update**: An example that reproduces the problem:

Given a page with the html:

```
<fieldset class="dartPayer-Insurance" style="width: 730px;">
    <select id="dartPayer-Payer" style="width: 235px;">
        <option value="UMA">UMA</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

And a page object defined as:

```
class MyPage
    include PageObject

    select_list(:payer_insurance){ element(:class => "dartPayer-Insurance").select_list_element(:id => "dartPayer-PayerList") }

    def input_payer(field, input)
        self.send(field, input)
    end
end
```

Running the following code:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto('C:\Scripts\Misc\Programming\PageObject\test.htm') 
page = MyPage.new(browser)

field = "payer_insurance="
input = "UMA"
page.input_payer(field, input)
```

Generates the following exception:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/page-object-0.9.0/lib/page-object/platforms/watir_webdriver/page_object.rb:968:in `instance_eval': (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
{:class=>"dartPayer-Insurance"}(identifier)
                                ^
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/page-object-0.9.0/lib/page-object/platforms/watir_webdriver/page_object.rb:968:in `find_watir_element'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/page-object-0.9.0/lib/page-object/platforms/watir_webdriver/page_object.rb:907:in `element_for'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/page-object-0.9.0/lib/page-object/element_locators.rb:11:in `element'
from pageobject.rb:7:in `block in <class:MyPage>'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/page-object-0.9.0/lib/page-object.rb:379:in `instance_eval'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/page-object-0.9.0/lib/page-object.rb:379:in `call_block'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/page-object-0.9.0/lib/page-object/accessors.rb:1089:in `block in standard_methods'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/page-object-0.9.0/lib/page-object/accessors.rb:246:in `block in select_list'
from pageobject.rb:10:in `input_payer'
from pageobject.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Before downvoting me, could you please explain why, so that I may fix it for the next time?

Comment: You are likely being downvoted due to people not understanding how to reproduce your problem. I updated your question to include a working example that expands on the code to reproduce the problem. Hopefully that will allow for re-opening of the question.

Comment: I will add an answer if the question gets re-opened, but in the mean time, the code you need is `select_list(:payer_insurance){ element(:fieldset, :class => "dartPayer-Insurance").select_list_element(:id => "dartPayer-Payer") }`. When using `element`, you need to specify the tag name. Excluding it causes the exception you are seeing. The id for the select list was also incorrect.

Comment: Oh, sorry about the id being off. It has some variables in it (like #{VIEW} ), and I must have messed it up when I edited it. I have the correct id in my code. 

Thank you for editing the question. I will endeavor to write a higher quality questions from your example. I am extremely grateful for your help. 

The proposed fix does function for me, and I will set you as the answer as soon as you add one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

The accessor you want for the select list is:

```
select_list(:payer_insurance){ element(:fieldset, :class => "dartPayer-Insurance").select_list_element(:id => "dartPayer-Payer") }
```

**Problem**

You were getting the syntax error due to the following part:

```
element(:class => "dartPayer-Insurance")
```

In the [API docs for `element`](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/ElementLocators#element-instance_method), you can see that method definition is:

```
(Object) element(tag, identifier = {:index => 0})

Finds an element

Parameters:
    the (Symbol) — name of the tag for the element
    identifier (Hash) (defaults to: {:index => 0}) — how we find an element. You can use a multiple paramaters by combining of any of the following except xpath
```

The original code was missing the `tag` parameter, which caused the exception.

Note that the select list id was also incorrect - using `dartPayer-PayerList` instead of `dartPayer-Payer`.